# I keep getting this error expecting a semi-colon, found '(', in line 288

Tags: apex

```
public with sharing class CS_AccountBrokerTriggerHandler {


    private integer BatchSize = 0;
    private Profile currentUserProfile;
    //private CS_TriggerHelper helper;

    public CS_AccountBrokerTriggerHandler (boolean isExecuting, integer pTriggerSize) {     
        // trigger is executing
        //TriggerIsExecuting = isExecuting;

        // set batch size
        BatchSize = pTriggerSize;

        // set current User profile
        //currentUserProfile = [Select Name From Profile where Id = :UserInfo.getProfileId()];

        // instantiate new trigger helper 
        //helper = CS_TriggerHelper.NewTriggerHelper(currentUserProfile.Name);
    }

    /**********************************************************
    * @Author       Rozelle Villanueva
    * @Date         MAR-13-2015
    * @Description  On After Insert trigger event handler on Account_Broker__c
    * @param        newAccBroker List of new Account_Broker__c
    * @Revision(s)
    **********************************************************/

    public void OnAfterInsert(Account_Broker__c[] newAccBroker) {
        try {
            System.debug('===ACCBROKER HANDLER====');                       
            map<Id, Profile> profileMap = new map<Id, Profile>([SELECT Id, Name From Profile WHERE Name like '%Producer -%']);
            String groupAccoutRT = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Group Account').getRecordTypeId();
            String householdRT = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Household').getRecordTypeId();
            map <Id,Id> accountToAccountProducerMap = new map <Id,Id>();

            if (CS_Utility.ValidateList(newAccBroker)) { //&& profileMap.containsKey(UserInfo.getProfileId())) {
            //if (CS_Utility.ValidateList(newAccBroker) && profileMap.containsKey(UserInfo.getProfileId())) {
                map <Id, Id> producerToAccountMap = new map <Id, Id>();
                Map<Id, Id> agentOfRecordMap = new Map<Id, Id>();
                List <Account_Broker__c> accBrokerToShareList = new List <Account_Broker__c>();  
                for (Account_Broker__c ab : newAccBroker) { 
                    accountToAccountProducerMap.put(ab.Account_Broker__c, ab.Id);
                    if((ab.Effective_Date__c <= date.Today() && date.Today() <= ab.Term_Date__c)
                        || (ab.Effective_Date__c <= date.Today() && ab.Term_Date__c == null)) {
                        producerToAccountMap.put(ab.Id, ab.Account_Broker__c);
                        accBrokerToShareList.add(ab);
                        if(ab.Producer_Type__c.equalsIgnoreCase('Agent of Record')) agentOfRecordMap.put(ab.id, ab.Account_Broker__c);
                        System.debug('producerToAccountMap===='+ producerToAccountMap);
                    }
                }
                CS_ObjectShareService.CreateSharingForAccountProducers(accBrokerToShareList);

                // JUN-23-2015 RCV Populate Standard and Preferred Agency lookup field on Account
                // Update Account's Broker Assigned field to true if there's an active account producer
                map <Id,Id> accountToStandardAccountBrokerMap = new map <Id,Id>();
                map <Id,Id> accountToPrefAccountBrokerMap = new map <Id,Id>();
                for (Account_Broker__c ab : [SELECT Id, 
                                                    Account_Broker__c,
                                                    Producer_Relationship__r.Preferred_Agency__c, 
                                                    Producer_Relationship__r.Agency__c,
                                                    Active_Broker__c
                                             FROM Account_Broker__c 
                                             WHERE Id IN: agentOfRecordMap.keySet() 
                                             AND Active_Broker__c = True 
                                             AND Producer_Type__c = 'Agent of Record']) {
                    accountToStandardAccountBrokerMap.put(ab.Account_Broker__c, ab.Producer_Relationship__r.Agency__c);
                    accountToPrefAccountBrokerMap.put(ab.Account_Broker__c, ab.Producer_Relationship__r.Preferred_Agency__c);
                    System.debug('accountToStandardAccountBrokerMap===='+ accountToStandardAccountBrokerMap);
                    System.debug('accountToPrefAccountBrokerMap===='+ accountToPrefAccountBrokerMap);
                }

                List <Account> accList = new List <Account> (); 
                for (Account a : [SELECT Id,
                                         Preferred_Agency__c,
                                         Standard_Agency__c,
                                         Broker_Assigned__c
                                  FROM Account WHERE Id IN: agentOfRecordMap.values()]) {
                    a.Broker_Assigned__c = true;
                    if (accountToStandardAccountBrokerMap.containskey(a.Id)) {
                        a.Standard_Agency__c = accountToStandardAccountBrokerMap.get(a.Id);
                    }
                    if (accountToPrefAccountBrokerMap.containskey(a.Id)) {
                        a.Preferred_Agency__c = accountToPrefAccountBrokerMap.get(a.Id);
                    }
                    accList.add(a);
                }
                if (accList.size() > 0) {
                    System.debug('accList===='+ accList);
                    update accList;
                    System.debug('updated accList===='+ accList);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            system.debug('ERROR : ' + ex.getMessage());     
        }       

    }

    /**********************************************************
    * @Author       Rozelle Villanueva
    * @Date         MAR-15-2015
    * @Description  On After update trigger event handler on Account_Broker__c
    * @param        newAccBroker List of new Account_Broker__c
    * @Revision(s)
    **********************************************************/

    public void OnAfterUpdate(map <Id,Account_Broker__c> oldAccBrokerMap,Account_Broker__c[] newAccBroker) {
        try {
            System.debug('OnAfterUpdate-=-=-=-----');   
            List <Account_Broker__c> accBrokerToCreateList =  new List<Account_Broker__c>();
            List <Account_Broker__c> accBrokerToDeleteList =  new List<Account_Broker__c>();
            map <Id, Id> producerToAccountMap = new map <Id, Id>();
            Map<Id, Id> agentOfRecordMap = new Map<Id, Id>();
            map <Id, Id> producerToAccInactiveMap = new map <Id, Id>();
            map <Id, Id> termAORMap = new map <Id, Id>();
            List <Account_Broker__c> newAccBrokerToCreateList =  new List<Account_Broker__c>();
            List <Account_Broker__c> oldAccBrokerToDeleteList =  new List<Account_Broker__c>();
            List <Account_Broker__c> oldAccBroker = new List <Account_Broker__c>();
            map <Id, Date> prodRelToTermDateMap = new map <Id, Date>();

            for(Account_Broker__c abLoop : newAccBroker) {
                if(abLoop.Producer_Type__c.equalsIgnoreCase('Agent of Record')) agentOfRecordMap.put(abLoop.id, abLoop.Account_Broker__c);  
                if(/*(abLoop.Effective_Date__c <= date.Today() && date.Today() <= abLoop.Term_Date__c)
                   || */(abLoop.Effective_Date__c <= date.Today() && abLoop.Term_Date__c == null)) {
                    producerToAccountMap.put(abLoop.Id, abLoop.Account_Broker__c);

                    // Create Sharing
                    System.debug('Create Sharing-=-=-=-----');
                    accBrokerToCreateList.add(abLoop);                      
                } else {
                    if (abLoop.Producer_Type__c.equalsIgnoreCase('Agent of Record')
                        && abLoop.Term_Date__c != oldAccBrokerMap.get(abLoop.Id).Term_Date__c) {
                        termAORMap.put(abLoop.Id, abLoop.Account_Broker__c);
                    }
                    // Delete Sharing
                    System.debug('Delete Sharing-=-=-=-----');
                    accBrokerToDeleteList.add(abLoop);   
                    producerToAccInactiveMap.put(abLoop.Id, abLoop.Account_Broker__c); 
                    prodRelToTermDateMap.put(abLoop.Producer_Relationship__c, abLoop.Term_Date__c);
                }
            }

            // Add or delete sharing
            if (accBrokerToCreateList.size() > 0) {
                CS_ObjectShareService.CreateSharingForAccountProducers(accBrokerToCreateList);
            }

            if (accBrokerToDeleteList.size() > 0) {
                CS_ObjectShareService.DeleteSharingForAccountProducers(accBrokerToDeleteList);
            }

            if (oldAccBrokerToDeleteList.size() > 0) {
                System.debug('delete old==='+ oldAccBrokerToDeleteList);
                CS_ObjectShareService.DeleteSharingForAccountProducers(oldAccBrokerToDeleteList);
            }


            // JUN-23-2015 RCV Populate Standard and Preferred Agency lookup field on Account
            // Set Account's Broker Assigned field to true if there are at least one active account broker

            map <Id,Id> accountToStandardAccountBrokerMap = new map <Id,Id>();
            map <Id,Id> accountToPrefAccountBrokerMap = new map <Id,Id>();
            for (Account_Broker__c ab : [SELECT Id, 
                                                Producer_Relationship__r.Preferred_Agency__c,
                                                Producer_Relationship__r.Agency__c,
                                                Account_Broker__c, 
                                                Active_Broker__c
                                         FROM Account_Broker__c 
                                         WHERE Id IN: agentOfRecordMap.keySet() 
                                         AND Active_Broker__c = True ]) {
                                         //AND Producer_Type__c = 'Agent of Record']) {
                accountToStandardAccountBrokerMap.put(ab.Account_Broker__c, ab.Producer_Relationship__r.Agency__c);
                accountToPrefAccountBrokerMap.put(ab.Account_Broker__c, ab.Producer_Relationship__r.Preferred_Agency__c);

            }

            List <Account> accList = new List <Account> (); 
            for (Account a : [SELECT Id,
                                     Preferred_Agency__c,
                                     Standard_Agency__c,
                                     Broker_Assigned__c,
                                     (SELECT Id, Account_Broker__c FROM Account_Brokers__r)
                              FROM Account WHERE Id IN: agentOfRecordMap.values()]) {
                for (Account_Broker__c ab : a.Account_Brokers__r) {
                    if (termAORMap.containsKey(ab.Id)){
                        a.Broker_Assigned__c = false;
                    } else {
                        a.Broker_Assigned__c = true;
                    }
                }
                if (accountToPrefAccountBrokerMap.containskey(a.Id)) {
                    a.Preferred_Agency__c = accountToPrefAccountBrokerMap.get(a.Id);
                }
                if (accountToStandardAccountBrokerMap.containskey(a.Id)) {
                    a.Standard_Agency__c = accountToStandardAccountBrokerMap.get(a.Id);
                }

                accList.add(a);
            }
            if (accList.size() > 0) {
                System.debug('updated accList===='+ accList);
                update accList;
                System.debug('updated accList===='+ accList);
            }

            // JUN-25-2015 RCV set Standard and Preferred to null if accout producer was termed
            List <Account> updateStandardAccountList = new List <Account>();

            List <Account> updateAccountList = new List <Account>();
            if (!producerToAccInactiveMap.isEmpty()) {
                for (Account a : [SELECT Id, 
                                         Standard_Agency__c, 
                                         Preferred_Agency__c 
                                  FROM Account 
                                  WHERE Id IN: producerToAccInactiveMap.values()]) {
                    a.Standard_Agency__c = null;
                    a.Preferred_Agency__c = null;
                    updateAccountList.add(a);
                }
            }

            if (updateAccountList.size() > 0) {
                System.debug('updateAccountList===='+ updateAccountList);
                update updateAccountList;
                System.debug('updated updateAccountList===='+ updateAccountList);
            }

            // Term related Census and Proposal Producers
            /*List <Census_Producer__c> toTermCensusProd = new List <Census_Producer__c> ();
            List <Proposal_Producers__c> toTermProposalProd = new List <Proposal_Producers__c> ();
            toTermCensusProd = [SELECT Id, 
                                       Producer_Relationship__c,
                                       Termination_Date__c,
                                       Census__r.Account__c
                                FROM Census_Producer__c 
                                WHERE Producer_Relationship__c IN: prodRelToTermDateMap.keySet() 
                                AND Termination_Date__c = null
                                AND Census__r.Account__c IN: producerToAccInactiveMap.values()];
            System.debug('toTermCensusProd ------'+ toTermCensusProd );
            toTermProposalProd = [SELECT Id, 
                                         Producer_Relationship__c,
                                         Termination_Date__c,
                                         Quote_Proposal__r.Apttus_Proposal__Account__c
                                  FROM Proposal_Producers__c 
                                  WHERE Producer_Relationship__c IN: prodRelToTermDateMap.keySet() 
                                  AND Termination_Date__c = null
                                  AND Quote_Proposal__r.Apttus_Proposal__Account__c IN: producerToAccInactiveMap.values()];
            System.debug('toTermProposalProd ------'+ toTermProposalProd );  

            for (Census_Producer__c cp : toTermCensusProd) {
                if (prodRelToTermDateMap.containsKey(cp.Producer_Relationship__c)) {
                    cp.Termination_Date__c = prodRelToTermDateMap.get(cp.Producer_Relationship__c);
                }
            }   
            if (toTermCensusProd.size() > 0) {
                System.debug('update toTermCensusProd-----'+ toTermCensusProd);
                update toTermCensusProd;
            }
            for (Proposal_Producers__c pp: toTermProposalProd) {
                if (prodRelToTermDateMap.containsKey(pp.Producer_Relationship__c)) {
                    pp.Termination_Date__c = prodRelToTermDateMap.get(pp.Producer_Relationship__c);
                }
            }
            if (toTermProposalProd.size() > 0) {
                System.debug('update toTermProposalProd-----'+ toTermProposalProd);
                update toTermProposalProd;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            system.debug('ERROR : ' + ex.getMessage());   
        }*/
    }

    /**********************************************************
    * @Author       Rozelle Villanueva
    * @Date         MAR-16-2015
    * @Description  On Before delete trigger event handler on Account_Broker__c
    * @param        newAccBroker List of new Account_Broker__c
    * @Revision(s)
    **********************************************************/

          **This is the line //  public void OnBeforeDelete(Account_Broker__c[] oldAccBroker) {//**
        try {
           // Delete Sharing
           CS_ObjectShareService.DeleteSharingForAccountProducers(oldAccBroker);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            system.debug('ERROR : ' + ex.getMessage());   
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

On the line *immediately* before the error:

```
        } catch(Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

Not only were you missing an extra curly brace,  you were also missing the entire catch part of a try-catch block.

Although, as a general practice, you should *not* wrap an entire method in a generic try-catch block like this. It will make it far more difficult to debug your code later.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is because there is an error before. Try adding that method somewhere else in the class and see if you get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing one more closing brace at the very end (to close the class itself). Uncomment 'OnBeforeDelete' and then add '}' as the very last line and see if that helps